# Analytic function on unit disk, Schwartz lemma type inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f:\Bbb{D}\to\Bbb{C}$ be an analytic function that satisfies the inequality $|f(z)|\le\dfrac{1}{1-|z|}.$
How can I show that $|f'(0)|\le 4.$

> Also, I am looking for the equality case. Is this a sharp upper bound?

Comment: What do you get from $\color{red}{Schwarz}$'s lemma ?

Comment: Here we can not apply it directly :)

Comment: Thank you :) Here I got $|f'(0)|\le 8.$ Is it correct?

Comment: Would you accept a proof that does not use Schwarz's Lemma?

Comment: @MarkViola: Yes. of course. I am glad to see such a solution.

Comment: Great!  I've just posted a solution that uses Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show that $|f'(0)|\le 4$ using Cauchy's Integral Formula

$$f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|= r<1}\frac{f(z)}{z^2}\,dz \tag1$$

Taking the magnitude of both sides of $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
|f'(0)|&=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r<1}\frac{f(z)}{z^2}\,dz\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{2\pi }\oint_{|z|= r<1}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z^2|}\,|dz|\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\frac{(2\pi r )\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)}{r^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{r(1-r)}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

The minimum of $\frac{1}{r(1-r)}$ occurs when $r=1/2$ in which case we have

$$|f'(0)|\le 4$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Nice. very nice :). But I do not think this as a sharp upper bound because $$\left|\dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}\right|\le\dfrac{2-|z|}{|z|(1-|z|)}$$ and the real function $F(x)=\dfrac{2-x}{x-x^2}$ can not take values between $3-\sqrt{8}$ and $3+\sqrt{8}.$ What do you think about the equality case?

Comment: That inequality seems valid, but how does one deduce anything regarding an estimate of $|f'(0)|$ from it?  $f'(0)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}+h(z)$, where $h(z)\to 0$ as $z\to $.  But the inequality as $z\to 0$ only gives $|f'(0)|\le \infty$, which doesn't give any information.

Comment: I see. Thank you Mark for your kind consideration.

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure and pleased it helped!

Comment: @user1952009 Ah, yes.  Thank you!  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

With the Schwarz lemma I get :

If $r \in (0,1)$ then for $|z| < 1$ : $|f(rz)| \le \frac{1}{1-r}$ and $|f(0)| \le 1$ so that $$g(z)=\frac{f(rz)-f(0)}{1+\frac{1}{1-r}}$$
is analytic on $\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ and $g(0) = 0$. Thus by Schwarz's lemma $$1 \ge  |g'(0)| = \left|\frac{r f'(0)}{1+\frac{1}{1-r}}\right|=|f'(0)|\frac{r(1-r)}{2-r}$$
whose optimum is [at $r \approx 0.6$](http://urlz.fr/5juQ) with $\frac{r(1-r)}{2-r} \approx 0.18$

I wonder if there is a way to improve this to $|f'(0)| \le 4$ as Mark Viola did with the Cauchy's integral formula.